# JavaScript jQuery ternary or .val() operator issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following code:

```
var result = $('#txtResult').val();
var input = $('#txtInput').val();
if (result == "0") {
    $('#txtResult').val($('#txtInput').val());
}
else {
    $('#txtResult').val($('#txtResult').val());
}
```

When i have **" result== '0' "** i want to change it with the input text box value and it works fine.

My question is why when i write it like this:

```
$('#txtResult').val($('#txtResult').val() == "0" ?
                    $('#txtResult').val($('#txtInput').val()) : $('#txtResult').val($('#txtResult').val()));
```

use ternary (question mark) operator the result text box and .val() from jQuery it shows me **[object Object]** on the result text box.
If i try to debug it using f11 first it work fine, but without debugging doesn't work fine.

Comment: Please consider to use an `if` statement, for readability and futur mainteners headhaches-free

Comment: I will. Thanks for advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because you're setting a jQuery object as the value.

You could simplify it to:

```
var result = $('#txtResult').val();
$('#txtResult').val($(result == 0 ? '#txtInput' : '#txtResult').val());
```

As a side note, you should probably be [parsing the value as a number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) so that you are comparing a number to `0` rather than a string.

```
var result = parseInt($('#txtResult').val(), 10);
$('#txtResult').val($(result === 0 ? '#txtInput' : '#txtResult').val());
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm newbie and i apologize if the question is stupid.

Comment: I parsing the value as number but in another function. Thanks for the note i appreciate your help mate.

Answer (score 4):

I think you've confused yourself a little with the inline-if statement.

In your example, you're setting the value of `txtResult` to the object that jQuery returns when you set a value using `val()`.

Instead of:

```
$('#txtResult').val($('#txtResult').val() == "0" ?
                    $('#txtResult').val($('#txtInput').val()) : $('#txtResult').val($('#txtResult').val()));
```

It should just be:

```
$('#txtResult').val($('#txtResult').val() == "0" ?
                    $('#txtInput').val() : $('#txtResult').val());
```

Comment: Thanks a lot mate. I'm newbie and i apologize if the question is stupid.

Comment: No need to apologise, we all need a little help every now and then :-)